# MVC5 placeholder for input not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

My code is like this

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedUser, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" ,@placeholder = "Your Placeholder Text"  }})
```

I expect the placeholder to come up as I added in the code, but it's not showing. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?
Output HTML

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="CreatedUser" name="CreatedUser" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" style="cursor: auto;  background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Comment: Does the `class` work? Post the outputted HTML

Comment: This will not work with `EditorFor`

Comment: @mattytommo Nop. Class also not working. Added output HTML

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Can you please answer this with correct format to do this?

Comment: Assigning `htmlAttributes` to `EditorFor()` is only applicable for MVC-5.1

Comment: @StephenMuecke is there no way to add placeholder and class together to "EditorFor " in 5.0 ??

Comment: You can but only if you create a custom `EditorTemplate` for the type pass the attributes as a `ViewDataDictionary`. I suggest you use `TextBoxFor()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That `EditorFor` overload that accepts the `htmlAttributes` is MVC 5.1 only.

See [HERE](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes)

If upgrading is not an option, use `TextBoxFor`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreatedUser, new { @class = "form-control" ,@placeholder = "Your Placeholder Text" })
```

Comment: is there no way to add placeholder and class together to "EditorFor " in 5.0 ??

Comment: @Athul Unfortunately not.

Comment: @mattytommo why not use TexBoxFor?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad That's what I said in my answer? In some cases (such as custom editor templates) using `TextBoxFor` may not be suitable.