# How to put html entity in Asp.net mvc Html helper EditorFor placeholder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-helpers

If i use raw html `<input />` with placeholder like:

```
<input id="TextSearch" name="TextSearch" placeholder="&#xf002;" type="text" value="" style="font-family: 'FontAwesome'" />
```

it renders like:
[image]
that is fine. But if i use Asp.net mvc Html helper like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TextSearch, new { placeholder = "&#xf002;", style="font-family: 'FontAwesome';" })
```

it renders like:
[image]
it can't render FontAwesome icon. It treats as string.

How can i render it correctly using Html helper `@Html.EditorFor()` ?

Comment: Can you add the actual HTML being rendered by the HTML helper to help identify the root cause? Something is getting html-encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to used **HttpUtility.HtmlDecode** for this, so your HTMLHelper should be like below,

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TextSearch, new { htmlAttributes = new { @PlaceHolder = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#xf002;"), @Style = "font-family: 'FontAwesome'" } })
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the `placeholder` and `style` HTML attributes as `additionalViewData`, not `htmlAttributes` (see `EditorFor` with 2 overloads [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_EditorExtensions_EditorFor__2_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Object_)). A simple `TextBoxFor` with `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` should work for all MVC versions:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextSearch, new { @placeholder = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#xf002;"), @style = "font-family: 'FontAwesome'" })
```

Take note that usage of `htmlAttributes` inside `EditorFor` [only works for MVC 5.1 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901705/mvc5-placeholder-for-input-not-working). If you're using MVC version 5.1+, you should use this `EditorFor` setting, otherwise use `TextBoxFor` helper as mentioned above:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TextSearch, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#xf002;"), @style = "font-family: 'FontAwesome'" }})
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jNDsVF) to see the difference of both helpers.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.